# show phone numbers in cordova contact plugin's pickcontact

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova contact plugin's pickContact method, the popup is showing just names and not numbers, please suggest some solution and see my code and screenshot below.

```
function doContactPicker() {    
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function (contact) {        
        alert('The following contact has been selected:' + JSON.stringify(contact));        
    }, function (err) {
        alert(err);
    });
}
```

What i get is

[image]

What i want is

[image]

Comment: You should ask the maintainer of this plugin..

Answer (score 0):

This plugin launches an external Activity for picking contacts. So view cannot be customized. 
If you want customize view then use find contact method. 
The search content can be given as a filter and contact object returned will contain all the details like phone number, display name. You can display as you want in your custom view using html.

Refer https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#example-1